# Mobile Mark 25 bench marking software question

Tags: discussion

Is this site appropriate for asking a question about the Mobile Mark Benchmarking Software? Especially if I am having issues with running it?

Comment: Yes, that would be on topic.

Comment: Perhaps just to make it clear: while the product mentions "Mobile", it's not for mobile phones/tablets but for PC-based "modern mobile office user".